# Using a Dictionary to write data in columns using Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Data in `test.csv` contains only country and dept. This gets filled in at `writer.writerow(data)`.

I've added extra columns using:  `writer = csv.DictWriter` then  `writer.writeheader()`.

I'm trying to fill in the columns added using data in a dictionary dicts. The data will fill up to about 200 rows in that column.

```
import json
import csv

def parse_file(input):
    with open(input, 'r') as input:
        content = input.readlines()
        csv_file = open('test.csv', 'wb+')

        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=["employee_id", "firstname", "lastname", "country", "dept"], delimiter=',')
        writer.writeheader()

        dicts = [{'employee_id':'123456', 'firstname':'Tom', 'lastname':'jones' }]

        for line in content:
            line_segments = line.split('\t')

            data = json.loads(line_segments[0])

            writer.writerow(data)

            for d in dicts:
                print(d['id'])
                writer.writerow([d['employee_id'],d['firstname'],d['lastname']])
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_file.py", line 36, in <module>
    parse_input_file(args.input_file)
  File "parse_file.py", line 25, in parse_input_file
    writer.writerow([d['femployee_id'],d['firstname'],d['lastname']])
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\csv.py", line 152, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda3\\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: '123456', 'Tom', 'Jones'
```

Comment: `dicts = [{'employee_id':'123456', 'firstname':'Tom', 'lastname':'jones' }]` Wrong idea cos `employee_id` is `123456` , so header is static can you write only values ! need write `["123456","Tom","jones"]` not include keys !

Answer (score 1):

As the error in the traceback states:

```
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames:
```

The dictionary that comes from the query contains more key than the field names you specified in the DictWriter constructor.

in **csv.DictWriter** ,you have specified **fieldnames** as :

```
fieldnames=["employee_id", "firstname", "lastname", "country", "dept"]
```

But you are passing only three dict values in this line :

```
for d in dicts:
    print(d['id'])
    writer.writerow([d['employee_id'],d['firstname'],d['lastname']])
```

What you need is updation of dictionary named **dicts**, Like this :

```
dicts = {'employee_id':'123456', 'firstname':'Tom', 'lastname':'jones','country':'some_country_name', 'dept':'some_dept' }
```

The final updated code should look something like this :

```
import json
import csv

def parse_file(input):
    with open(input, 'r') as input:
        content = input.readlines()
        csv_file = open('test.csv', 'wb+')

        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=["employee_id", "firstname", "lastname", "country", "dept"], delimiter=',')
        writer.writeheader()

        dicts = {'employee_id':'123456', 'firstname':'Tom', 'lastname':'jones','country':'some_country_name', 'dept':'some_dept' }

        for line in content:
            line_segments = line.split('\t')
            data = json.loads(line_segments[0])
            writer.writerow(data)
            writer.writerow(dicts)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But the problem is that the data for "country", "dept" are coming from the inputed file at parse_file(input). The first three columns specified in the dictionary are ones I am adding

Comment: Is there a way to put something in those columns so they are ignored? and just write for every row the value given in the ones in the dictionary?

Comment: can I add something like in 'some_country_name writer.fileldnames[3]' for instance?

Comment: @Samantha I was'nt online then.Wait I am trying to solve it now.

Comment: @Samantha did you try this line exactly as it is ..??      dicts = {'employee_id':'123456', 'firstname':'Tom', 'lastname':'jones','country':'some_country_name', 'dept':'some_dept' }
     writer.writerow(dicts)

Comment: @Samantha I am trying to debug your code. Wait for some time.